# How to duplicate sheet in excel and rename it?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a excel file named **Salary.xlsx** and the first sheet named **week1**

I want duplicate automatically **week1** and rename to **week2**, **week3**, **week4**, . . .**weekn**

How can i do that in Python with Pandas or another framework?

Code like this:
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx',sheet_name="week-1")

n = 40

for i in range(0,40):
  copy week-1 then rename to week-i
  add week-i to my_file.xlsx
```

Automatically copy and rename sheet name.

> => the **Salary.xlsx** have sheet **week1, week2, week3, week4, weekn**,

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code!

Comment: @James i updated code in the post

Comment: Is this homework? You wrote pseudocode instead of a comment, this looks like someone else wrote it

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for ignoring the `pandas` tag, but imho, openpyxl is the better module if this is just about manipulating an excel spreadsheet. To achieve, what you want to achieve with openpyxml, you can use [Workbook.copy_worksheet](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.copy_worksheet):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("Salary.xlsx") # load worksheet
origsheet = wb["Week1"]           # Reference to source of copies
for i in range(2,53):             # Create copies 2-52
    duplicate = wb.copy_worksheet(origsheet)
    duplicate.title = f"Week{i}"

wb.save("Salary_new.xlsx")        # save under new name
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
# read week-1
df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx', sheet_name='week-1')

# open your file to add sheets
my_file_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a')

n = 40

for i in range(2, n):
    # add week-i 
    df.to_excel(my_file_writer, index=False, header=True, encoding='utf-8', sheet_name=f'week-{i}')

# save file
my_file_writer.save()
```

Comment: How to keep source format(sheet week-1) when copy bro, i run this code, but sheet copied not had format(color, data type)

Comment: df.to_excel(my_file_writer, header=True, ...., keep_format = "True" ) how to do that bro. I want to keep source format

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx',sheet_name="week-1")
n = 41
for i in range(2,n):
     s = 'Sheet' + str(i)
     df.to_excel( 'my_file.xlsx', sheet_name=s)
```

Please follow indentation properly ...